# Is it bad to make a cookie every second or less?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am currently making a timer in javascript and I want to make sure that if you close the browser that its not just lost...so as my clock is ticking away I am storing a cookie every 100ms.

It's every 100ms as I am using the system time instead of just a system interval so I am basically just calculating the difference in time between the start and now and just want to update that as nicely as possible.

I could reduce it to 500ms I guess but its still basically doing the same thing...

I'm just wondering if storing cookies this way is a bad thing in any way and if it is a bad thing is there a better way to be doing this?

Cheers!

Comment: This may or may not be on-topic. I'm not an expert in these matters, just a potential warning. PS: That might make your website laggy, right?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing timers in cookies though. Instead of doing there, try  calculating the ending time of the timer and storing that instead. Then, every time the page is loaded, calculate remaining timer time through deducting the ending time saved in cookies from current time.

Comment: Why do you think you need to store anything that often? The only value you'd need to store is the `timestamp` when the timer runs out. The only reason to ever update it is if this timestamp changes; maybe because of a pause/play function? `var time = (timestamp - Date.now()), h = Math.floor(time/360000)%24, m=Math.floor(time/60000)%60, s=Math.floor(time/1000)%60;` here you have your timer, completely independant of any interval. Whenever you compute this value, it will show you the correct remaining time.

Comment: @Feathercrown Well I haven't had an issue with this but both of the computers I am using to make / test this are of a decent spec so yeah...its a concern...

Comment: @LFlare The timers are counting up to 8 hours but I dont see how if the browser is closed by mistake or there is a crash I can store the time that it crashed or was incorrectly closed.

Comment: @Thomas as stated before I am counting up, not down...the reason I want to store cookies with every "tick" is because I would like the user to be able to get the information back within 2 hours of the latest time in the event of a browser crash or accidentally pushing the back button or something like that. If that mistake is made im not sure how I can record it and make sure a cookie is set for 2 hours after the time of the crash.

Comment: @MatthewJonat If you are counting up, store the time that the stopwatch was started at. Then calculate it. That way, you won't have to keep changing cookies.

Comment: Yeah...I get that I can do that but then how do I store a cookie for 2 hours after now? ...and when I say now I mean any time that the browser might crash or the window is mistakenly closed...I want a cookie to be set for two hours from now...as the timer keeps ticking..I want it to be 2 hours from the current time of the timer as it is counting...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the "big picture" is, but here is my take on it.

If your web page is showing a count-down to a certain event, I would split the responsibility between server side code and client side.

On page-load get data from the server on time-remaining and start the timer. No need to store anything in cookies. On page-load, you can get the data from the server again, so nothing is lost.

Comment: I'm assuming OP in this case is not involving a server in this scenario. A pure timer application using Javascript and cookies. In which, the better solution would be to calculate the datetime when a timer would finish and storing that in the cookies. On page-load, take the final time in the cookies and calculate time remaining from current time.

Comment: Well actually there is a server side part to the application although for this that is irrelevant...at least at this point...so consider it a pure JS app. Also, and maybe I should have been clearer about this but its a timer counting up...not down. The maximum time its counting up to is 8 hours at present but I will implement something where the user can set that at a later time. It will only be stored in the server when it gets paused or the person is finished timing that specific job and clicks "finish / end / stop". I am trying to account for mistakenly closing the browser or crashes here.

Comment: A cookie set in javascript is all within the browser and does not go over the network. It is not terrible to do this, just unusual.

I would still recommend you to consider keeping the timer status on the server, you could send it to the server when the user sets it. You read it from the server on page load. The rest of the time, it is just a timer going on in the browser, no communication to the server needed.